# Safe alternative to exec(sql)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, security, dynamic-sql, sql-injection

I've found some `exec(sql)` statements buried in the code.  They're there for good reason, because these statements couldn't be written directly, however they are an obvious attack vector.

Is there a safe alternative to `exec(some sql)`?  Something that will be paremetrised correctly, including table names in statements?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For certain types of parameterization, it's not going to matter if you use `EXEC()` or `sp_executesql`, because some things can't be parameterized anyway. For example, you expressed in the comments (please update your question to be more specific about your requirements!) that you are parameterizing table names, but these can't be parameterized because they need to expressed literally to SQL Server (it can't tokenize that and swap at runtime).

To protect yourself from table name vulnerabilities, you can easily protect yourself like this:

```
DECLARE @tablename sysname; -- pretend this is a parameter
SET @tablename = N'this_is_not_a_table';

-- in procedure body:
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE name = @tablename)
BEGIN
  RAISERROR(N'Table does not exist.', 1, 11);
  RETURN;
END
SET @sql = N'SELECT ... FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@tablename) + ...;
-- EXEC(@sql) or EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql
```

Now, I prefer to use `sp_executesql` always, partly because it promotes using strongly-typed parameters (avoiding SQL injection issues as well as double-single-quote issues), but also because in some cases you will be passing parameters for both parameterizable and unparameterizable values (yes I made those words up). More info:

- [Bad Habits to Kick : Using EXEC() instead of sp_executesql](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql)
- [Protecting Yourself from SQL Injection - Part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-1/)
- [Protecting Yourself from SQL Injection - Part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-2/)

*Now the only thing you have to worry about is if someone is able to create tables and can create a table named `sys.objects; DROP TABLE foo; --` - but if you have someone you don't trust but has the ability to create tables in your database...*

Comment: If you use quotename on that table, I think it is safe even with a name like drop.

Comment: Seems silly that you have to parameterize on table. You could just partition your data in the same table with a surrogate key instead....

Comment: @jmoreno Of course, thanks, I harp on that all the time.

Comment: @Aron Sure, in an ideal world we would never need dynamic SQL at all. Then there's reality, where we don't have control over the table design and the set of tables/columns being queried.

Comment: That is why one should introduce the table designers to my friend [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @Aron You can scream Bobby Tables up and down all day long, and you're still going to continuously run into people who **have to** parameterize table names.

Comment: @Aron I agree, however we sometimes inherit databases.  Fixing those can often be a hell of alot of quite high risk\high hazard work.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at using [sp_executeSQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) instead. It is fully paramaterized and so provides a much greater sense of safety to dynamic queries (and using alongside [EXECUTE AS USER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362.aspx) within procedures with strict permission sets make it even better).

Comment: I saw that one, but was getting some mixed messages in that it wasn't _really_ injection proof.  Is that true?

Comment: @BanksySan It depends on what you pass to it, of course. Not everything can be parameterized (for example, you can't parameterize table names and column names). But there are ways to protect yourself even from that type of injection vector. For some further information, see [Bad Habits to Kick : Using EXEC() instead of sp_executesql](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql) and ...

Comment: ...[Protecting Yourself from SQL Injection in SQL Server - Part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-1/) and [Part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-2/).

Comment: Bugger, table names are exactly the thing I want to parameterise.